# How to remove an item while iterating over collection?

Tags: actionscript-3, loops

I would like to use the AS "for each" syntax to loop over a collection of items. Within the loop I sometimes need to remove an item from the collection I am iterating over.

Using a "for" loop, I would code this like (**note the "--" operator to move the index back**):

```
for (var n:int=0; n<ac.length; n++) {
    var s:String = ac.getItemAt(n) as String;
    if (s == 'c')
        ac.removeItemAt(n--);
}
```

Is it also possible to do something similar using a "for each" construct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all of the languages I know of, the `foreach` requires that the collection it iterates through does not change while iterating.

So, the simple answer would be - no, you can't. But the way you're doing it in your sample is OK.

*edit*: What you could do is to create a new list of items that need to be deleted inside a foreach(of itemList), and than go through another foreach(of deletedItems) and remove from itemList. The only thing is to worry about is that you don't iterate over the collection you're changing.

Comment: Your suggestion doubles up the work. It's much better to do it with a single pass using a regular `for` loop.

Comment: Note that you have to decrement the loop index n only if the index of the item to remove is less or equal than n

Answer (score 3):

Copy your `arraycollection` or your data structure. Do a `reverse for loop` on your original
and remove the elements at the required index from the copied structure.

Output: Your new data structure minus the elements you dont want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if the `for each` construct you are talking about allows access to an index during the iteration but even then it is sure to backfire because I am certain most languages assume the collection is not suddenly going to change its "length" or its indices during the iteration if you are using `for each`. If you put in a index parameter then you are back to a regular `for` construct so the whole exercise ends up being futile.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible with the **for ... in** loop. The iteration is not disrupted.

```
var o:Object = { a: 0, b: 1, c:2 };
for (var k:String in o)
{
   delete o[k];
}
```

Comment: The question was: "Is it also possible to do something similar using a "for each" construct?"